# How do I handle a mousedown event inside a window in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, mouseevent

How do I handle a mousedown event inside a window in Cocoa?

My code:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"yay");
}
```

I am using Mac OS10.6, in xcode 4.0.1.

EDIT:
Yes, this is in the app delegate, but this is my .h:

@interface jumperAppDelegate : NSWindow  {

Which I have done before in app delegates (just not for mouse events). This is really annoying me

Comment: Besides the missing leading `-` (i.e. `-(void)mouseDown:`), this is correct. What's your question?

Comment: It wont work (sorry i left out the - but its in my code).

Comment: Are you sure you are adding this code to an NSWindow implementation? Maybe you added it to the application delegate or something like that?

Comment: Your app delegate inherits from NSWindow? That is an exceedingly strange design choice - the app delegate is a controller, not a view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you inherit from `NSWindow`, as well as conform to the `<NSWindowDelegate>` protocol.  Like this:

```
@interface YourWindow : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> {}
@end
```

Then you should receive the event notification.

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {    
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if conforming to `NSWindowDelegate` is necessary. Just give it a shot anyway.

Comment: That is still not working, which is strange. I has already inherited NSWindow, and i did NSWindowDelegate which was no help. I dont know whats going on

Comment: @Conor:  Are you sure you don't have some window/view that is above the one you're trying to register mouseDown events for? Maybe it's absorbing the notifications.  Also, try doing what sosborn said, namely returning YES on `acceptsFirstResponder`.

Comment: I am using the AppDelegate and MainWindow.xib as my window. The only other files I added are to make it go fullscreen. I also changed to NSWindow, but to no avail... I dont know what to do

Comment: @Conor:  That's your problem.  Your delegate should NOT inherit from NSWindow.  You need to make a custom view (afaik) and hook it up to a new custom class that inherits from NSWindow.

Answer (score 2):

For this method to be called the class it is being called in needs to inherit from NSResponder. Windows and views are all subclasses of NSResponder. If the class you are calling this from is not a subclass of NSResponder then the method will not fire.

*** Update ***
Also be sure to override acceptsFirstResponder to return yes.

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I have heard that in your header file (.h) that you need to replace the "NSObject" with "NSWindow". I would test it but I am not at my computer right now.

Also, make sure that you put the following code into your header file:

```
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)event;
```

EDIT: I have done some tests and research, but I cannot get it to work. I have two tips though.

- Use the '-acceptsFirstMouse method.
- Try creating an NSEvent:

  NSEvent * someEvent;
  -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)someEvent;

This probably won't work, but I will have more information tomarrow

Comment: No need for putting that in the header file.  It's a notification, so the compiler doesn't need to see a header declaration.